# AmoCRM как добавить элемент каталога при создании сделки add/catalog_elements_id PHP?

Tags: php

Создаю сделку и пытаюсь в нее добавить элемент каталога 
add/catalog_elements_id.
Проштудировал https://www.amocrm.ru/developers/content/api/leads но без результатно, помогите разобраться как работает catalog_elements_id на PHP

```
$this->
    addRequest['request']['leads']['add'][$index]['catalog_elements_id'] = [
         1321 => [1036583 => 1]
    ];
```

Тут:

**1321** - это существующий catalog_id(список);

**1036583** - это catalog_element_id - который принадлежит каталогу

**1** - это как я понимаю количество этих элементов

Comment: Укажите весь код, по мимо этого какая ошибка возникает?

Comment: Код там очень большой и ошибки нет. Сделка отправляется и создается. Просто есть один кастомный список с итемати и хочу привязать определенный итем из списка к этой сделке. В итоге, сделка создается, но итем не привязывается.